# How to align 3 blocks of text correctly

Tags: html, css, header

i would like to know how to get 3 columns of text on the same line with 3 headers like.

I've already tried adding divs with classes although i may have made mistakes but using the text alignment option doesn't seem to be working.

[This website has the 3 columns of text with 3 headers and is the desired layout i want but i am having trouble with the code.](http://www.emanuelelivi.com/)

Thanks for all the help guys

Comment: Can you show us some code, possibly in fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the HTML:

```
  <div id="first">
    this is first div with first text
  </div>

  <div id="second">
    this is second div with second text
  </div>

  <div id="third">
    this is third div with third text
  </div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
   #first{
    --background:black;
    text-align:left;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    color:orange;
   }
   #second{
    --background:orange;
    text-align:center;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    color:blue;
    margin-left:20px;
   }
   #third{
    --background:blue;
    text-align:right;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    color:orange;
    margin-left:20px;
   }
```

This is all what I have got from your question! you can modify this code according to your requirements

Answer (score 1):

Div is a block element so text-aliment won't affect that.
Example, HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="test">
    <p>Some text</p>    
  </div>
  <div class="test">
    <p>Some text</p>    
  </div>
  <div class="test">
    <p>Some text</p>    
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper { width: 800px; }
.wrapper .test { width: 200px; display: inline-block; margin: 0 20px; }
.wrapper .test p { text-align: justify; }
```